# Python Pylab pcolor options for publication quality plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to make DFT (discrete fourier transforms) plots using `pcolor` in python. I have previously been using Mathematica 8.0 to do this but I find that the colorbar in mathematica 8.0 has bad one-to-one correlation with the data I try to represent. For instance, here is the data that I am plotting:

```
[[0.,0.,0.10664,0.,0.,0.,0.0412719,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.351894,0.,0.17873,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.10663,0.,0.178183,0.,0.,0.,0.0405148,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.177586,0.,0.,0.,0.0500377,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0588906,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.0493811,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.0397341,0.,0.0399249,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]]
```

So, its a lot of zeros or small numbers in a DFT matrix or small quantity of high frequency energies.

When I plot this using mathematica, this is the result:

[image: DFT plot with mathematica 8.0]

The color bar is off and I thought I'd like to plot this with python instead.
My python code (that I hijacked from [here](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/10/visualizing-correlation-matrices.html)) is:

```
from numpy import corrcoef, sum, log, arange
from numpy.random import rand
#from pylab import pcolor, show, colorbar, xticks, yticks
from pylab import *


data = np.array([[0.,0.,0.10664,0.,0.,0.,0.0412719,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.351894,0.,0.17873,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.], 
[0.10663,0.,0.178183,0.,0.,0.,0.0405148,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.177586,0.,0.,0.,0.0500377,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0588906,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.0493811,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.0397341,0.,0.0399249,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]], np.float)

pcolor(data)
colorbar()
yticks(arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10))
xticks(arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10))
#show()
savefig('/home/mydir/foo.eps',figsize=(4,4),dpi=100)
```

And this python code plots as:

[image: DFT plot in python with pcolor]

Now here is my question/list of questions:
I like how python plots this and would like to use this but...

1. How do I make all the "blue" which represents "0" go away like it does in my mathematica plot?
2. How do I rotate the plot to have the bright red spot in the top left corner?
3. The way I set the "dpi", is that correct?
4. Any useful references that I should use to strengthen my love for python?

I have looked through other questions on here and the user manual for numpy but found not much help.

I plan on publishing this data and it is rather important that I get all the bits and pieces right! `:)`

### Edit:

Modified python code and resulting plot! What improvements would one suggest to this to make it publication worthy?

```
from numpy import corrcoef, sum, log, arange, save
from numpy.random import rand

from pylab import *


data = np.array([[0.,0.,0.10664,0.,0.,0.,0.0412719,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.351894,0.,0.17873,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.10663,0.,0.178183,0.,0.,0.,0.0405148,0.,0.,0.],   
[0.,0.177586,0.,0.,0.,0.0500377,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0588906,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.0493811,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.0397341,0.,0.0399249,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.],
[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]], np.float)

v1 = abs(data).max()
v2 = abs(data).min()
pcolor(data, cmap="binary")
colorbar()
#xlabel("X", fontsize=12, fontweight="bold")
#ylabel("Y", fontsize=12, fontweight="bold")
xticks(arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10),fontsize=19)
yticks(arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10),fontsize=19)
axis([0,7,0,7])
#show()


savefig('/home/mydir/Desktop/py_dft.eps',figsize=(4,4),dpi=600)
```

[image: Improved python code's output DFT plot]

Comment: Looks like you've got your answer, but you could also look at using pcolormesh, which is significantly quicker than pcolor...

Comment: @pelson Thank you! Your comment is much appreciated! `:)` I wish to move from mathematica to python and have been having significant difficulties saving mathematica "interpolating function polynomials" into discrete data to use in python! `:(`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will get you closer to what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.OrRd)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10))
plt.colorbar()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

The list of available colormaps by default is [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps). You'll need one that starts out white.

[image]

If none of those suits your needs, you can try generating your own, start by looking at [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap).

Comment: Interesting! thank you! However, I was trying to figure something out: why does the colormap range end at `0.32`? Why doesn't this `0.32` go to the extreme top extent? It looks like the last `0.04` was omitted from being plotted! `:P`

Comment: Your data gets normalized to the range 0.0 - 1.0, then the colormap is applied. By default the max of your data gets mapped to 1.0, the min to 0.0. The largest value in your data is 0.351894, so that will be the ending point of your colormap. You can change this behavior by specifying `vmin` and `vmax` in your call to `pcolor`, e.g. `plt.pcolor(data, cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=0.4)` will display that last 0.4 on the colormap, but your darkest point will not be as black as before.

Comment: I did try `vmin` and `vmax` but that threw an error message at me. I'll try to reproduce it...

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, in Mathematica 9.0:

```
GraphicsGrid@{{MatrixPlot[l, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {Min@l, Max@l}]] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False], BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, Max@l}}]}}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! I realize that, thank you! `:)` However I don't have access to mma 9 **off-campus**. I only have mma 8 access off-campus....

Comment: @drN, note that even Mathematica has not labeled the colorbar up to the maximum point as you proposed. It behaves just (very similar) like the Python solution provided above.