# Plotting all data files in a directory

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot all my data files in a directory in python and then saving the resulting the plots. I am **not** trying to write efficient python code (unfortunately): just interested in plotting data for now.

I am a newbie at python and my object is to get figures organized in my dissertation.

So with the below code, this is what I am trying to do:

1. I list all `.dat` files with `glob`
2. I populate an array with the file names
3. I loop through this file names array and `plot_surface` each of the data files

The data that I trying to plot is [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/profiledata.zip)

The errors that are spat out at me are:

### Errors

```
  File "/home/dnaneet/Research/test_collection/dftdata/profile2.py", line 59, in <module>
    plot(x, y, z)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2286, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3783, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 317, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 278, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError, 'third arg must be a format string'
ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

### Python code

> ```
> import os
> import glob
> import sys
> import subprocess
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
> import numpy as np
>
> from numpy import *
> from numpy.random import rand
> from pylab import pcolor, show, colorbar, xticks, yticks
> from pylab import *
>
> print 'Listing all profile/dat files'
> profilefilelist = glob.glob('*profile*.dat')
> raw_input('Press ENTER to continue...')
> print profilefilelist
>
>
> for i in profilefilelist:
>   DATA = i
>   def get_data(fname=DATA):
>     '''Read 2d array of z coordinates from file. Convert to float values
>     and wrap in a numpy array.'''
>     with open(fname) as f:
>         data = [map(float, line.split()) for line in f]
>     return np.array(data)
>     def plot(x, y, z):
>
>         fig = plt.figure()
>         ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
>         ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5,cmap="binary",linewidth=0.1)
>         ax.set_zlim3d(0.0,4.0)  
>         ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
>         ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
>         ax.set_zlabel('h(X,T)',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
>         savefig(os.getcwd()+DATA+'.pdf',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
>         savefig(os.getcwd()+DATA+'.pdf',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
>
>
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     z = get_data()
>     x = range(z.shape[0])
>     y = range(z.shape[1])
>     x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
>     plot(x, y, z)
> ```

### Question

Is this as a result of my poor indentation or is something more sinister going on over here? What should I do to correct these errors?

I don't understand python very well and have been trying to move away from mathematica (since I will graduate and can't afford the mathematicas or matlabs of the world anymore).

### Previous code as offered on SE:

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022815/957560)

### Modified code (based on answers)

> ```
> import os
> import glob
> import sys
> import subprocess
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
> import numpy as np
>
> from numpy import *
> from numpy.random import rand
> from pylab import pcolor, show, colorbar, xticks, yticks
> from pylab import *
>
> print 'Listing all profile/dat files'
> profilefilelist = glob.glob('*profile*.dat')
> raw_input('Press ENTER to continue...')
> print profilefilelist
> DATA=profilefilelist
>
>
> for i in DATA:
>     def get_data(fname=i):
>         '''Read 2d array of z coordinates from file. Convert to float values
>         and wrap in a numpy array.'''
>         with open(fname) as f:
>             data = [map(float, line.split()) for line in f]
>             return np.array(data)
> for i in DATA:    
>     def my_plot(x, y, z):
>         fig = plt.figure()
>         ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
>         ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5,cmap="binary",linewidth=0.1)
>         ax.set_zlim3d(0.0,4.0)  
>         ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
>         ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
>         ax.set_zlabel('h(X,T)',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
>         plt.show()
> #        savefig(os.getcwd()+DATA+'.pdf',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
> #        savefig(os.getcwd()+DATA+'.pdf',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)    
>
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>             z = get_data()
>             x = range(z.shape[0])
>             y = range(z.shape[1])
>             x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
>             my_plot(x, y, z)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clean up suggestions (your task is rather simple, there are some unnecessary operations I think):

- Don't iterate the index of a list, iterate the list itself;
- Get rid of the boilerplate code (printing, `raw_input` just for confirmation, etc.)
- Take advantage of array creation routines.
- Don't create functions that are called just in one place.
- Avoid multiple imports, or the `from module import *`, since it is already causing name conflicts.

Here is a modified version of your program, I believe it achieves the same results. It's not a solution for your question, but rather a collection of small improvements (or what I think to be improvements):

```
import os
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

for fname in glob.glob('*profile*.dat'):

    z = numpy.loadtxt(fname)

    x,y = np.meshgrid(range(z.shape[0]), range(z.shape[1]))

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5,cmap="binary",linewidth=0.1)
    ax.set_zlim3d(0.0,4.0)

    ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
    ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
    ax.set_zlabel('h(X,T)',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
    plt.savefig(os.getcwd()+fname+'.pdf',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
    plt.savefig(os.getcwd()+fname+'.pdf',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
```

Optionally you could use, in the last two lines:

```
plt.savefig(os.path.join(os.getcwd, "%s.pdf" % fname), figsize=(5,5), dpi=600)
```

Comment: +1 Some good advice in general, but I personally wouldn't tell a python learner _not_ to define functions, even if they are only called once, since most beginners (myself included) start off by writing one long imperative script with no logical functional structure.

Comment: Sorry, there was a closing parenthesis missing, so the interpreter points the error to the next line. I will correct it.

Comment: @askewchan that's a point, but defining functions that are called in only one place is sort of a bad practice in my point of view. And also, there is nothing wrong about using a long imperative script in this case. The very problem formulation (run-once, non-interative batch processing) ASKS for a minimalistic solution.

Comment: @heltonbiker If you can edit your code to include `z = np.array(data)` immediately after `data = numpy.loadtxt(fname)`, this would be the exact answer to my question! Having said that I think the kind of help I received on here **from everyone** is just tremendous.

Comment: @drN The function `numpy.loadtxt` already returns an array, so you don't have to first load the file and then convert the loaded data to array (it is already done in one step, no need to `[map(float, line.split()) for line in f]` since something equivalent is done internally). Also, it already creates an array of type `float` by default, since this is the most common numeric type used for scientific applications. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: (so I'll edit the question using `z` instead of `data` for that variable name. Also, if you could mark my answer as accepted, I would be very happy :o)

Comment: Now, why didn't you use `data = np.loadtxt(f)` instead of `data = np.loadtxt(fname)`? The former seems to make more sense doesn't it? (to a n00b at any rate...)

Comment: @drN In fact, the entire `open` clause is unnecessary, as `np.loadtxt` accepts either a file object (`f`) or a filename (`fname`).  If it receives a string, it assumes it's a filename and it opens the file for you.

Comment: You are right. I kept the `open` inadvertently, because it was in the original code. Will edit to cut this out.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one indentation problems that I can see (though I don't have all the dependencies to reproduce this).

Your def plot(x,y,z) is inside of the def get_data function (which is inside your for loop).

You only need to define your functions once, so you can dedent the def get_data and def plot lines to start at column 0.  Then your

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

block will call your plot function instead of pyplot (as seen in the traceback).

also, instead of defining the get_data in the for loop, you would just need to call it with the DATA file you are looking for.

Comment: You are right. mY function now starts in column 0. However there is one erro that I have to deal with now.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your own function and named it `plot`, but when you call `plot(x,y,z)` it looks like it's calling the standard `pyplot.plot` command (see the location of code in your traceback).  Try renaming it to `my_plot` for example.

In general and in this case, strongly recommend against naming your own objects (functions and variables) with names given to other commonly used functions.

As @tstone notes, your function definitions are inside of a loop, define them before you run the loop, but also give them unique names.  With a unique name, you will still be able to use the ordinary `plot` function if you wish, as well as you'd have caught the scoping error (that it's defined in the loop) because the unique name (`my_plot`, e.g.) would have been undefined.

Try restructuring your script like this:

```
import ...

def get_data(fname):    #fname is now a required argument, to be fed in by the loop in __main__ body
    '''Read 2d array of z coordinates from file. Convert to float values
    and wrap in a numpy array.'''
    ...

# should pass DATA to the savefig:
def my_plot(x, y, z, DATA):
    ...
    savefig(...DATA...)

# do everything else here:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Listing all profile/dat files'
    profilefilelist = glob.glob('*profile*.dat')
    raw_input('Press ENTER to continue...')
    print profilefilelist

    # you didn't need `i` since you just immediately assigned it to DATA, just call it DATA in the first place
    for DATA in profilefilelist:
        z = get_data(DATA)
        x = range(z.shape[0])
        y = range(z.shape[1])
        x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        my_plot(x, y, z, DATA)       # Here, pass DATA to `my_plot`
```

Note that I changed the argument for `get_data` so that it doesn't have a default argument, but that it will accept a variable (here called `DATA` that comes from the loop).

Comment: I redefined my function as `my_plot`. IT says now that `NameError: name 'my_plot' is not defined`. Why is that? I changed `plot` to `my_plot` in the last line of the code and `def my_plot`

Comment: @drN Haha, I just mentioned that would happen in my edit :P  It's because you should move your definition of `my_func` to before the loop, and run the loop under the `__main__` part of your script.

Comment: Now, it says `get_data` is not defined... after I move `my_plot` before the loop

Comment: @drN Put both definitions in the front, then run the loop in the `__main__` body.

Comment: This is quite horrible. I don't seem to understand the sytactic structure of python neither do I have the time to understand it! `:(` Will see what I can do about this and make an edit. sigh...

Comment: @drN, it's not as bad as it looks.  Think of the `def` of a function as assigning the value to a variable.  If you wanted to use `x = 2` in the main part of your script, you wouldn't say `x = 2` several times in a loop.  That's all I really changed.

Comment: I know what you are saing and thank you for tyour patience. I think I got the hang of it (modified code appended). I think I have an error with my `savefig` now. Should that not be in a for loop for incremental file names with the same name as the data file?

Comment: @drN You must pass the filename to it through `my_plot`, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes... I just did that... I need a book to learn python from. I am unsure I can learn this from web snippets. Any suggestion?

Comment: @drN Try [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) and the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) for general introductions to the language.  You'll also (if you're doing data analysis) want to [learn numpy](http://scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll go over these references.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example to help you understand how functions and loops work.

```
# Here I define bar 10 times, but call it 1 times
# This is what you're doing in your code
print "defining bar 10 times"
for i in range(10):
    def bar(i):
        print "bar " + str(i)
print "running it once"
bar(99)

# Here I define foo once, and call it 10 times
# This is what I think you're trying to do
print "defining foo once"
def foo(i):
    print "foo " + str(i)

print "running foo 10 times"
for i in range(10):
    foo(i)
```

This is the output of the above code:

```
defining bar 10 times
running it once
bar 99
defining foo once
running foo 10 times
foo 0
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 4
foo 5
foo 6
foo 7
foo 8
foo 9
```